# Selecting latest package versions in multiple package Octopus job

Tags: c#, rest, jenkins, nuget, octopus-deploy

I have an Octopus project that will deploy multiple packages each with different release versions. An application and a rest service.

The default behavior is to set the package version for each package to the version of the release package. For example if I want to deploy a release version 1.0.0.5 it will look for version 1.0.0.5 of every package referenced in the project. So if the application is one release ahead of the rest service the deployment will fail as the rest service version 1.0.0.5 doesn't exist.

There's an option in the edit release screen to specify the latest package. Is there a way to set the default behavior to use the latest version of packages rather than specifying the release version ?

Comment: I think you're confusing release versions with NuGet package versions. Can you explain how your project's deployment process is configured? It sounds like you're using a variable to tie release versions and NuGet versions together, but that's a bit presumptuous on my part. Octopus has two release versioning mechanisms: variable template and NuGet package versioning. Which are you using?

Comment: Sorry I only seen this comment. Yes I was getting confused between release versions and Nuget package versions. I think I also found the problem, the version number of the packages showing in octopus are being set in my Jenkins job and pushed to octopus rather than being set in Octopus. So it looks like I just need to reconfigure the Jenkins job to push the correct version of the packages.

Answer (score 1):

When Octopus creates a release, it selects the latest version of each package by default.

Additionally, it will create a version for the release, which is not related to the version numbers of the packages (because there may be many different version numbers within all of the packages in your project).

You can sync the version number Octopus uses by going to:

```
Project -> Settings -> Release versioning
```

And selecting the option:

> Use the version number from an included NuGet package

And then selecting the step from the drop-down list.